# Not able to get the Value from Drop down Menu

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Hello I'm having problem in getting the value from the drop down menu bar. When I choose a course and submit no Value is retrieved but a new empty record is entered in DB. I'm sharing my code I will appreciate any sort of help.
[image: Here in the image I am getting the data for drop down menu]

My View

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo(base_url()."University/std_assign_cousrse/");?>" >       
<select>
 <option value="">--- Select Course ---</option>
<?php

foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo "<option value=".$row['course_id'].">".$row['course_name']."</option>";
}
 ?>
</select>
<input type="Submit"> 
</form>
```

My Controller

```
   public function std_assign_cousrse()
    {
        $data = array(
            'std_course' =>$this->input->post('course_id') ,);
    $this->db->Insert('tbl_student',$data);
    print_r($data);

    }
```

Comment: use name attribute in input type, e.g <select name="myselect">

Comment: You need to give a `name="course_id"` to the select

Comment: hello @Shahzaib Ahsan if you got your answer then close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use name attribute

```
<select name="myselet">
 <option value="">--- Select Course ---</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the select tag:

Simply add `<select name="course_id">`. and this is done.

Comment: Getting the value now can you tell me the logic of this how it's working.

Comment: When you post something to server, the PHP or any server side language needs a name/reference, the source of data. So, when you post a form, the form is a source from which data is to be received. After that, you need value like what do you want from that form? A name, email, comment, user id or any detail. So, here, course_id is a key that has specific value that you set in <select> tag. And its posted from the form, and received using $this->input->post('course_id') means, get input_id value that was posted by the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mention the name of the  tag..
Proper tag should be

```
<select name='course_id'>
 <option value="">--- Select Course ---</option>
<?php

foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo "<option value=".$row['course_id'].">".$row['course_name']."</option>";
}
 ?>
</select>
```